# Does getapplicationlabel returns non Latin characters?

Tags: android

Hi I want to pass installed Apps name to server for this I am using getApplicationLabel but server does not accept other than english character ,so  I want to know whether `getApplicationLabel (ApplicationInfo info)` returns only English character or it may return non english character (like Chinese, hindi )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't only return Latin characters.

There are at least two ways it won't.

1. If the app is only localized for a non-Latin alphabet, say some obscure Indian or Chinese app. The application probably isn't named using the basic Latin alphabet.
2. If the app is localized for many languages and the current device language is using a non-Latin script, such as Google Chrome. On a device with the language set to Chinese, `getApplicationLabel()` would likely return "谷歌浏览器".

Comment: Hi TheWanderer Thanks for reply, yes my app supports many different languages including Chinese, so it means getApplicationLabel() will return non latin (non english) character is it like?

Comment: Have you localized the application name?

Comment: Hi I am not talking about only may application. My application is reading installed application name on users device. If on user device 300 app are present then I will send these 300 app name to server

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Ok. Yes I have  localized the application name

Comment: If you've localized it to any non-Latin scripts then `getApplicationLabel()` will return that script on any device with a matching language.